# How to use an operation which is defined in another namespace in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-keyword

I have a definition for an operation in a namespace and I want to use it in another name space, how I can do this:

for example, assume that I have this: operation defined:

```
namespace op
{
       inline cv::Matx21f operator/(const cv::Matx21f &v, float a)
    {
        return cv::Matx21f(v(0) / a, v(1) / a);
    }
}
```

and I have code in another namespace as:

```
namespace code
   {
          void my function()
           {
              cv::Matx21f data=getData();
              cv::Matx21f result=data/10;
             }
   }
```

I am getting error on

```
  cv::Matx21f result=data/10;
```

as / is not define.

I know that I can use:

```
  use namespace op;
```

but I don't want to do so if possible.

Any way I can resolve the operation similar to what we can do with name resolution with functions (op::/  is not valid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code instead:

```
namespace WhateverLibraryNs
{
    inline namespace operations
    {
        inline cv::Matx21f operator/(const cv::Matx21f &v, float a)
        {
            return cv::Matx21f(v(0) / a, v(1) / a);
        }
    }
}
```

Client code within `WhateverLibraryNs` will use the operator seamlessly (because it is an *inline* namespace).

Client code outside of `WhateverLibraryNs`, will have four options:

First, fully qualify the operator:

```
auto result = WhateverLibraryNs::operations::operator/(v, a);
```

Second, import the operations namespace, only (see std::string_literals namespace for a similar solution):

```
using namespace WhateverLibraryNs::operations;
auto result = v / a;
```

Third, alias the inner namespace:

```
namespace ops = WhateverLibraryNs::operations;
auto result = ops::operator/(v, a);
```

Fourth, import the operator only:

```
using WhateverLibraryNs::operations::operator/;
auto result = v / a;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have three options. You could bring in the operator directly:

```
       void my function()
       {
          using op::operator/;
          cv::Matx21f data=getData();
          cv::Matx21f result=data/10;
       }
```

You could call it directly:

```
       cv::Matx21f result = op::operator/(data, 10);
```

But ideally, you just put `operator/` in the correct namespace:

```
namespace cv {
    inline Matx21f operator/(const Matx21f &v, float a);
}
```

That way, `cv::Matx21f result=data/10;` just works because the operator would be found.